# Calculation of CRC-16

Tags: c, encoding, crc16

I am currently using the CRC-16 algorithm posted in:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/73085244406/

```
unsigned short const crc16_table[256] = {
0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040
};


unsigned short crc16(unsigned short crc, unsigned char const *buffer, unsigned int len)
{
    while (len--)
        crc = (unsigned short)((crc >> 8) ^ (crc16_table[(crc ^ (*buffer++)) & 0xff]));
    return crc;
}
```

I need an implementation as follows:
Polynomial: 0x8005
Initial Data: 0x0000
MSB first (not reversed)
No final XOR calculation

My Test Data is:

```
        byte0 = 0xE3;
        byte1 = 0x23;
        byte2 = 0x1C;
        byte3 = 0x20;
        byte4 = 0x00;
        byte5 = 0x00;
```

Checking this using the tool:
http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html
I get the result "B5E3" as can be seen here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PvJO.png)

The "B5E3" result is what I want to get from the code above, however I get the result "CED5" which seems to be another implementation of the CRC-16.
If I change the setting on the above online tool to "reverse data bytes" + "reverse CRC result before final XOR" I get "CED5" which is the same what I see in my implementation using the above code. This imples that the code above implemented the "reverse data bytes" + "reverse CRC result before final XOR". I was wondering if someone could modify the above code so that the data bytes are not reversed and that the final CRC result is also not reversed before the final XOR.

Comment: Please decide on *one* language to use in your tags. This wouldn't be valid C#, for one thing - please remove that, and ideally use either C or C++ but not both.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=crc16+implementation+in+c

Comment: There's lots of different CRC16 and lots of incorrect implementations at that. You can't really salvage the posted code in case the table was generated with a different polynomial than the one you need.

Comment: The tool pycrc (https://pycrc.org/) can generate c code for different crc implementations. The list https://pycrc.org/models.html shows different crc models and what command to use to generate them. Maybe this helps

Comment: To be a bit more explicit about lookup tables: Each polynomial comes along with its own table. The site there is fine if you need just *any arbitrary* polynomial, if you need a specific one, as in your case, it is without any value as it does not even specify *which* polynomial it implements.

Comment: Please read [this painless guide](https://archive.org/stream/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt) to learn more on CRC and how to generate your own table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe, and what your desired result corresponds to, is CRC-16/UMTS. The description from [Greg Cook's catalog](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm) is:

```
width=16  poly=0x8005  init=0x0000  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0xfee8  residue=0x0000  name="CRC-16/UMTS"
```

[crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) can generate C code for any such specified CRC, and does so automatically for all of the CRCs in that catalog. An example from that code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint16_t const table_byte[] = {
    0x0000, 0x8005, 0x800f, 0x000a, 0x801b, 0x001e, 0x0014, 0x8011, 0x8033, 0x0036,
    0x003c, 0x8039, 0x0028, 0x802d, 0x8027, 0x0022, 0x8063, 0x0066, 0x006c, 0x8069,
    0x0078, 0x807d, 0x8077, 0x0072, 0x0050, 0x8055, 0x805f, 0x005a, 0x804b, 0x004e,
    0x0044, 0x8041, 0x80c3, 0x00c6, 0x00cc, 0x80c9, 0x00d8, 0x80dd, 0x80d7, 0x00d2,
    0x00f0, 0x80f5, 0x80ff, 0x00fa, 0x80eb, 0x00ee, 0x00e4, 0x80e1, 0x00a0, 0x80a5,
    0x80af, 0x00aa, 0x80bb, 0x00be, 0x00b4, 0x80b1, 0x8093, 0x0096, 0x009c, 0x8099,
    0x0088, 0x808d, 0x8087, 0x0082, 0x8183, 0x0186, 0x018c, 0x8189, 0x0198, 0x819d,
    0x8197, 0x0192, 0x01b0, 0x81b5, 0x81bf, 0x01ba, 0x81ab, 0x01ae, 0x01a4, 0x81a1,
    0x01e0, 0x81e5, 0x81ef, 0x01ea, 0x81fb, 0x01fe, 0x01f4, 0x81f1, 0x81d3, 0x01d6,
    0x01dc, 0x81d9, 0x01c8, 0x81cd, 0x81c7, 0x01c2, 0x0140, 0x8145, 0x814f, 0x014a,
    0x815b, 0x015e, 0x0154, 0x8151, 0x8173, 0x0176, 0x017c, 0x8179, 0x0168, 0x816d,
    0x8167, 0x0162, 0x8123, 0x0126, 0x012c, 0x8129, 0x0138, 0x813d, 0x8137, 0x0132,
    0x0110, 0x8115, 0x811f, 0x011a, 0x810b, 0x010e, 0x0104, 0x8101, 0x8303, 0x0306,
    0x030c, 0x8309, 0x0318, 0x831d, 0x8317, 0x0312, 0x0330, 0x8335, 0x833f, 0x033a,
    0x832b, 0x032e, 0x0324, 0x8321, 0x0360, 0x8365, 0x836f, 0x036a, 0x837b, 0x037e,
    0x0374, 0x8371, 0x8353, 0x0356, 0x035c, 0x8359, 0x0348, 0x834d, 0x8347, 0x0342,
    0x03c0, 0x83c5, 0x83cf, 0x03ca, 0x83db, 0x03de, 0x03d4, 0x83d1, 0x83f3, 0x03f6,
    0x03fc, 0x83f9, 0x03e8, 0x83ed, 0x83e7, 0x03e2, 0x83a3, 0x03a6, 0x03ac, 0x83a9,
    0x03b8, 0x83bd, 0x83b7, 0x03b2, 0x0390, 0x8395, 0x839f, 0x039a, 0x838b, 0x038e,
    0x0384, 0x8381, 0x0280, 0x8285, 0x828f, 0x028a, 0x829b, 0x029e, 0x0294, 0x8291,
    0x82b3, 0x02b6, 0x02bc, 0x82b9, 0x02a8, 0x82ad, 0x82a7, 0x02a2, 0x82e3, 0x02e6,
    0x02ec, 0x82e9, 0x02f8, 0x82fd, 0x82f7, 0x02f2, 0x02d0, 0x82d5, 0x82df, 0x02da,
    0x82cb, 0x02ce, 0x02c4, 0x82c1, 0x8243, 0x0246, 0x024c, 0x8249, 0x0258, 0x825d,
    0x8257, 0x0252, 0x0270, 0x8275, 0x827f, 0x027a, 0x826b, 0x026e, 0x0264, 0x8261,
    0x0220, 0x8225, 0x822f, 0x022a, 0x823b, 0x023e, 0x0234, 0x8231, 0x8213, 0x0216,
    0x021c, 0x8219, 0x0208, 0x820d, 0x8207, 0x0202
};


uint16_t crc16umts_byte(uint16_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc = (crc << 8) ^
              table_byte[((crc >> 8) ^ data[i]) & 0xff];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: Mr. Adler might know a thing or two about this sort of thing :)